# Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of odd order in a finite group. Show that $a^2$ and $b^2$ commute if and only if $a$ and $b$ commute.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I really don't know how to solve this problem. I just know that if $|a|=2k_1+1$ and $|b|=2k_2+1$, then,

$a^{2k_1+1}=e=a^0$ and  $b^{2k_2+1}=e=b^0$. Also, if $|G|=n$, then, $2k_1+1,2k_2+1\equiv 0 \pmod n$.

Comment: By the way, [the converse is always true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282046/if-ab-ba-prove-a2-commutes-with-b2/1282050).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got it the other way round. It's $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2k_1 + 1}$ and $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2k_2 + 1}$.

Suppose $a^2b^2 = b^2a^2$. Then:
\begin{align*}
ab &= a^{2k_1+1}(ab)b^{2k_2+1} \\
&= a^{2k_1+2}b^{2k_2+2} \\
&= (a^2)^{k_1+1}(b^2)^{k_2+1} \\
&= (b^2)^{k_2+1}(a^2)^{k_1+1} \\
&= b^{2k_2+1}(ba)a^{2k_1+1} \\
&= ba
\end{align*}

Comment: What if $a$ and $b$ have even order?

Comment: @Heriberto then we can't conclude anything. Just take any $S_n$, and transpositions have order $2$, so if $a$ and $b$ are two distinct transpositions, then $a^2$ and $b^2$ are both $e$ and hence commute. However, distinct transpositions do not commute.

Comment: How did you know that $(a^2)^{k_1+1}(b^2)^{k_2+1}=(b^2)^{k_2+1}(a^2)^{k_1+1}$?

Comment: @kman Start by proving the identity for $k_1 = k_2 = 2$, and convince yourself that you can repeat the same proof for higher values.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $a = (a^2)^m$ if $a$ has order ...

Answer (score 2):

1. If $x$ commutes with $y$, then x commutes with every power of $y$: by induction, we have that if $xy^k=y^kx$, then 
   $$xy^{k+1}=(xy^k)y = (y^kx)y = y^k(xy) = y^k(yx) = y^{k+1}x.$$
   And if $x$ commutes with $y^k$, then it commutes with $y^{-k}$: from $xy^k=y^kx$, multiplying by $y^{-k}$ on both sides we get $y^{-k}x = xy^{-k}$.
2. If $a^2$ commutes with $b^2$, then it commutes with every power of $b^2$.
3. If $b$ has odd order, then $b$ is a power of $b^2$.